# Right click open terminal on same directory

Tags: shell, terminal, centos, centos7

I recently updated from centos6 to centos7. In centos6 I could right click on the terminal and select `Open Terminal` and that would open a terminal in the same directory as the parent shell.

In centos7 when I right click and select `Open Terminal` the directory of the  subshell will be /home/user  and not the same as the parent shell. I would like to have the same behavior as in centos6.

According to [this website](http://satyadeepk.in/2011/02/quicktip-right-click-to-open-terminal-in-current-directory-in-ubuntu/) a solution would be to install `nautilus-open-terminal` however I have no superuser permissions to install such package.

How can I solve this problem without `nautilus-open-terminal`?

Answer (score 0):

The command `gnome-terminal` will open a new terminal in the same directory. So I added:

```
alias o='gnome-terminal'
```

to `.bashrc`. Right click and 'Open Terminal' is still not working but at least I get the desired behavior by typing `o`.